# Two icons for one input field

Tags: website-design, gui-design, material-design

I have the following puzzle. There is the main icon for the field and icons for specific item in drop-down menu. I depict them in this way:

[image]

Are there any examples of such ui? What could you advise me to improve my ui?

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like the skill level icons could be omitted, are they really providing meaningful information to understand the option?

Comment: It's a trick question! The answer is to not use any icons, right? :)

Comment: The field icon is conflicting semantically with the icon for the specific item. The graduate's hat implies an advanced level of skills.

Comment: @Ideogram I have seen such hats used in academic ceremonies starting in kindergarten. It does not universally signify advanced knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot think of another UI that I have seen using icons for both the field and the specific item.

My advice to you is to think why you really use icons. UI design has been moving from using the icons to using only the words. A good example is spotify that has kept only the words. I believe that icons should be used when they are easy for the user to remember and conventional. In the example that you have used, I am not even sure what the icon for the advance represents.

> Icons are fast to recognize at a glance (if well designed) — particularly true for standard icons that people have seen and used before.

Resource: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/

> I had one goal in mind when writing this article: to remind us all to ask ourselves why we're using icons on websites we create. For many of us it has become an automatisation to include them in our projects as a matter of course. Next time, ask yourself what the added value of that extra icon is and how it compares to the other icons on the website.

Resource: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/use-and-abuse-of-icons-in-the-modern-age--webdesign-17064

Answer (score 5):

*Following on @Dimitra Miha's answer:*

The icon in the dropdown menu just **adds clutter to the interface and no comprehension benefits** (the icon for "Advance" doesn't signify advanced academic level). Therefore, my suggestion is to **remove the skill level dropdown icon**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Edward Tufte came up with a concept called the **data-ink ratio** in his 1983 book Visual Display of Quantitative Information.

> Good graphics should include only data-Ink. Non-Data-Ink is to be
>   deleted everywhere where possible. The reason for this is to avoid
>   drawing the attention of viewers of the data presentation to
>   irrelevant elements.The goal is to design a display with the highest
>   possible data-ink ratio (that is, as close to the total of 1.0),
>   without eliminating something that is necessary for effective
>   communication.

This concept was adapted by Stephen Few to be more aligned with digital displays, so he talks about the **data-pixel ratio** in his book Information Dashboard Design.

However, in both cases you want to *maximise* the data-ink/data-pixels, and *minimise* the non-data-ink/non-data-pixels.

So in your situation, the icons are essentially non-data-pixels, so unless you can really justify their purpose (and "they look good" is not a good justification), they should be removed as they are not providing any tangible value.